# Use of lexer SETTEXT with the c target

Tags: text, antlr, lexer

I'm trying to change the text of a token using the C target.

From the docs for the SETTEXT macro: "However if you wish to change the text that the token represents you can use this macro to set it explicitly."

```
TOKEN: 'token' { SETTEXT("text"); }
```

SETTEXT is expecting a pANTLR3_STRING.  How can I provide it one for a string literal?

Or is there another way of doing this..?

Thanks